# Launch crop image activity before setting wallpaper

Tags: java, android, image

In my application users can click a button to set an image from imageview as wallpaper.

Here is the code:

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
    .getInstance(getApplicationContext());

try {
    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(
        ((BitmapDrawable) fullSizeImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
    //setResource(fullSizeImage.getDrawable());
    Toast.makeText(
        FullSizeImageDisplay.this,
        "Wallpaper set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It is setting the image as wallpaper, but not working properly on all devices, where only a part of the picture is set as wallpaper.

I want user to get an option to crop the image before setting it as wallpaper, like Android shows before setting an image as wallpaper from Gallery.

Can that activity from Gallery be launched from my app to crop image or is there another alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start an intent in onActivityResult after loading Image. There You could start the cropping with this intent, for example:

```
     Intent cropYourPicIntent = new Intent(
                "com.android.camera.action.CROP");
```

But this is only to get the idea of it what I mean, there is a lot of more code to do.